# Verify if order id exists

Tags: paypal, transactions

I redirect the user to a page with the Smart Payment Buttons passing the order id in the URL

```
example.site?orderid=D23F34492211
```

But if the user changes the URL, the JavaScript will fetch an id that doesn't exist. Eventually, the transaction will not be completed, however, it will just close the PayPal's lightbox as well as the credit card option, without giving any error message.

The error it throws is something as following:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PayPalHttp\HttpException: {"name":"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND","details":[{"issue":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","description":"Specified resource ID does not exist. Please check the resource ID and try again."}],"message":"The specified resource does not exist.","debug_id":"9d62d83a871b8","links":
```

Is there any way to get this response as JSON or get the error code from the API and show an error message to the user? If not, what's the best way to verify whether the order id exists or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be passing the order ID via a URL, you should be fetching it from your server. Then you will know it is valid.

Anyway, your question is bout verifying the status of an order ID via an API call. It is not necessary to do this. You should not have to do this. But if you insist on doing it, there is an API call you can use. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_get

This API call should be run from your server, so if you want to call it from the client, you will need to build a middleware endpoint route on your server.  (Again, there is no point to doing this and it would be wasted effort)

The actual proper way to do things is to fetch the order ID from your server, as mentioned: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Yeah because actually my setup is: `costumer chooses the product -> costumer is redirect to a checkout page (in the website) -> user proceed to payment (that's where the the order id is generated and his info saved to the database)-> user is redirected to a payment page with the payment buttons and order id->payment button will fetch this order id in the url`  Because it's already working actually, i found this the easiest way. I could also save the order it to the database and compare it.

Comment: Also, do i have to save the order id and payer id to the database or just the transaction id? Because after the payment completed, I redirect the user to a success page with the order id, payer id and transaction id. `example.site?id=2DNDJDJ3434payerid=TPXKANANAZAS&transaction=339DJSJSNNXIDF43243`

Comment: The transactionid is the only thing that needs to be persisted for accounting purposes. Anything else is more for debugging.

Comment: One more question: you said that the best way of doing it is fetching the order id from the server, but, in my case, how would I do it? Because after saving the user data to the database and generating the order id, the user is redirected to the payment page with the order id as parameter. How would I fetch it from the server?

Comment: The normal way of doing things is to have your own internal unique cart/tracking/invoice id, which is the sort of thing you pass around in a URL. When the button is clicked, you fetch and get a freshly created PayPal order ID, which you know is valid because it is created right then, on demand.